# FancyBox with iframe misrendering

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I added fancybox to a page to display a youtube or vimeo video when a person clicks on a thumbnail. When the popup opens everything looks fine but if you scroll on the page instead of staying in the fixed position the popup overlay and the popup itself scroll with the page. The iframe actually stays in it's fixed position though. Also it causes rendering artifacts to show up like duplicate popups.

It looks like it's actually some sort of rendering bug because the artifacts aren't really there. To fix this I added a scroll listener in javascript that adds and removes 1px of padding on the top of the body. This causes the browser to redraw the screen, i'm guessing, which repositions the overlay/popup and cleans up the artifacts.

This doesn't seem like a proper solution for this so I'm looking for alternate solutions to prevent this problem or at least a link to someplace confirming it's a rendering issue.

I'm using fancybox2 in the newest version of chrome on mac.

Comment: My guess is that there is something in your css that creates that behavior ... but it's just a guess, got a link?

Comment: I tried to set option fixed to false, after set it helps render popup properly, but I get problem with overlaying. `$.fancybox('test',{fixed:false});`

Answer (score 0):

My workaround

```
    options['fixed'] = false;
    options['afterShow'] = forceUpdateUI;
    options['afterClose'] = forceUpdateUI;

    $.fancybox(
        "hello world",options
    );


}
function forceUpdateUI(){
    $('body').addClass('dummy-class');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('dummy-class');
    },500);
}

    .dummy-class{
    padding-top:1px;
    }
```